# Flutter Provider, using child widget to update a list

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm new to using Flutter and I am currently struggling to understand how to use the Provider package for the following task, or if it is even the correct implementation in the first place.

I have a widget that uses another widget within itself to update a time value.

In the parent widget I have the following:

```
class _AddTimesScreenState extends State<AddTimesScreen> {
 List<TimeOfDay> times = [];
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(      
      body: Provider<List<TimeOfDay>>.value(
        value: times,
    child: SetTimes()
```

In the 2nd widget, which is used to update the times list by using a time picker I have:

```
class _SetTimesState extends State<SetTimes> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final times = Provider.of<List<TimeOfDay>>(context);
```

Essentially my goal is to be able to update the times list in the 2nd widget so it can then be used in the first widget. I have methods to add TimeOfDay objects to the list, but when the code is run the list in the first widget does not appear to be updated.

Am I using Provider in a way that it's intended, or have I completely misunderstood its application?

Thanks

Comment: Try ChangeNotifierProvider with Consumer

Answer (score 2):

In the **TimeOfDay** class make sure you are extending it with Change Notifier.

How does provider know it has to rebuild?

When the class (TimeOfDay in your case) extends ChangeNotifier, you are provided with a method called **notifylisteners()** , this triggers a rebuild to all the widgets consuming the provider. So you should call this in the function that is changing the objects data in your class TimeOfDay.

So make sure you are:

- extending ChangeNotifier in your class/model.
- calling notifylisteners when data is changed.

Example :

```
class MyClass extends ChangeNotifier{

int a = 0;

  addSomething(){
    //Here we are changing data
    a = a + 1;
    notifylisteners();
  }

}
```

let me know if this solves your error.